# How can I tell if PostgreSQL's Autovacuum is running on UNIX?

Tags: postgresql, unix, autovacuum

How can one tell if the **autovacuum daemon** in Postgres 9.x is running and maintaining the database cluster?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

## PostgreSQL 9.3

### Determine if Autovacuum is Running

This is specific to Postgres 9.3 on UNIX.
For Windows, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2027046/41906).

#### Query Postgres System Table

```
SELECT
  schemaname, relname,
  last_vacuum, last_autovacuum,
  vacuum_count, autovacuum_count  -- not available on 9.0 and earlier
FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

#### Grep System Process Status

```
$ ps -axww | grep autovacuum
24352 ??  Ss      1:05.33 postgres: autovacuum launcher process  (postgres)
```

#### Grep Postgres Log

```
# grep autovacuum /var/log/postgresql
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
```

If you want to know more about the *autovacuum* activity, set `log_min_messages` to `DEBUG1..DEBUG5`. The SQL command `VACUUM VERBOSE` will output information at log level `INFO`.

---

Regarding the Autovacuum Daemon, the Posgres docs state:

> In the default configuration, autovacuuming is enabled and the related configuration parameters are appropriately set.

See Also:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html

Answer (score 19):

I'm using:

```
select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where query like 'autovacuum:%';
```

in collectd to know how many autovacuum are running concurrently.

You may need to create a security function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pg_autovacuum_count() RETURNS bigint
AS 'select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where query like ''autovacuum:%'';'
LANGUAGE SQL
STABLE
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

and call that from collectd.

In earlier Postgres, "query" was "current_query" so change it according to what works.

Comment: This works if you run the query as the same user that is running autovacuum, otherwise the "query" field may just show <insufficient privilege>. Especially on AWS/GCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run pg_activity to see the currently running queries on your database. I generally leave a terminal open with this running most of the time anyway as it's **very** useful.

Answer (score 0):

set log_autovacuum_min_duration to the time length that you desire and the autovacuum execution exceeds the time length will be logged.